# What is the defined behavior in Python for no return statement being reached?

Tags: python, return

Given the following Python code:

```
def avg(a):
  if len(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)
```

What is the language defined behavior of `avg` when the length of `a` is zero or is its behavior unspecified by the language and thus should not be counted upon in Python code?

Comment: Note that this is pretty trivial to test - `def test(): pass` `print(test())`.

Comment: But if the behavior were undefined, such a test could vary in its result from one implementation to the next.

Comment: That's true, although it would be a pretty massive thing to have undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default return value is `None`.

From the [documentation on Calls](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> A call always returns some value, possibly `None`, unless it raises an exception. How this value is computed depends on the type of the callable object.

Comment: It's worth noting that this also applies to the `return` statement - if there is no following expression, it is exactly equivalent to `return None`. This can be useful to end the function explicitly, where you do not want to give a return value explicitly (it shows that the intention is to end the function, not to return `None` as a value).

Answer (score 0):

If `len(a)` is `0`, that will be treated as a `False`-like value, and your `return` statement won't be reached. When the flow of control drops out of the bottom of a function with no explicit `return` statement being reached, Python functions implicitly return `None`:

```
>>> print(avg([]))
None
```

If `len(a)` is not defined - in other words, if the object has no [`__len__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) method - you'll get a `TypeError`:

```
>>> print(avg(False))
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in avg
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```